# Android Camera.takePicture callback never called

Tags: android, android-camera

I know this question was asked multiple times already, but I couldn't find the answer that would work in my case. What I am trying to do is to call `takePicture()` on click event as follows:

```
   FrameLayout take_picture_btn = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.take_picture_btn);
    mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp;
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(activity.getContentResolver(), bitmap, imageFileName, "");
            editProfile.showPhotoEditor(true, bitmap);
        }
    };
    take_picture_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Camera cam = mPreview.getCamera();
            cam.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });
```

From other posts I figured out that the `camera.stopPreview()` or `camera.release()` should not be called too early and therefore I made sure that I am not calling those methods anywhere. However, it seems that stopPreview is being used somewhere, because camera preview freezes before the callback onPictureTaken is invoced. In adition the callback works fine on KitKat4.4, but it doesn't on Lollipop5.1

There are following messages in my logcat:

```
05-10 21:01:09.766 9613-9626/com.emplicore W/CameraBase: Camera service died!
05-10 21:01:09.766 9613-9626/com.emplicore W/CameraBase: mediaserver's remote binder Camera object died
05-10 21:01:09.766 9613-9613/com.emplicore E/Camera: Error 100
```

Which also proves that the camera has stopped before callback was invoked, however I don't understand why this happens, because I am sure that I am not stopping it.

Could it be be that some other events happening once a click event occurs do it for me? By the way, I also tried starting preview - `cam.startPreview()` before taking a picture, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: i recommend that you surround your problem statements with `try/catch` and then update the error messages.  dont forget to use `e.printStackTrace();` in your `catch`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to print anything new even if I surround it with try/catch. This error message probably is just a log message. If some method would throw an exception, Android Studio wouldn't ignore it.